# Nvim-treesitter colors doesnt pass to :TOhtml

Tags: neovim, treesitter

I'm trying to understand how I can copy code from Neovim as RTF.
So far I figured the easiest way is to convert the code to HTML and then convert the HTML to RTF, so using the `:TOhtml` is supposed to convert the given range to HTML and color it according to the colors in your Nvim editor but when using tree-sitter the colors doesn't convert.

When I convert a code to HTML without treesitter I get:

```html
<style>¬
<!--¬
pre { white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: monospace; color: #e4e4e4; background-color: #000000; }¬
body { font-family: monospace; color: #e4e4e4; background-color: #000000; }¬
* { font-size: 1em; }¬
.Operator { color: #af5f87; }¬
.Repeat { color: #d787d7; font-weight: bold; }¬
.String { color: #d7875f; }¬
.Comment { color: #5f875f; }¬
.LineNr { color: #b2b2b2; }¬
.Include { color: #d75f87; }¬
.Type { color: #5fafaf; }¬
.Number { color: #afd7af; }¬
.Special { color: #5fafff; }¬
.Function { color: #d7d7af; }¬
-->¬
</style>
```

But when I use treesitter I get:

```html
<style>¬
<!--¬
pre { white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: monospace; color: #e4e4e4; background-color: #000000; }¬
body { font-family: monospace; color: #e4e4e4; background-color: #000000; }¬
* { font-size: 1em; }¬
.LineNr { color: #b2b2b2; }¬
-->¬
</style>
```

so I need help either getting the `:TOhtml` to work with the treesitter or any other way to copy as RTF from Neovim on linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `TOhtml` command is inherited by Neovim from the upstream Vim, and it is written using the traditional Vim syntax highlighting techniques and know nothing about treesitter.

Try to disable treesitter highlighting (`TSBufDisable highlight`) on the buffer and use traditional highlighting.

Comment: Yup, this works. As a workaround, until a better solution is found, one can make a command mapping, e.g.:

`cmap tohtml TSDisable highlight \| TOhtml \| TSEnable highlight`